# enabling HTTP 2 to secure against Request smuggling - IIS 7 and cold-fusion 2016

Tags: http2

i have a coldfusion 2016 website running over IIS 7.0 . I want to ensure it is not susceptible to HTTP smuggling

i want to enable HTTP 2 to resolve this issue ..

Question : what all places i have to make changes to enable HTTP 2 ?

1. IIS
2. is there any setting in coldfusion 2016 process as well to enable HTTP 2?

below is some reference material on what HTTP smuggling is :

http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246928/HTTP%20Request%20Smuggling

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFllH0QccCs

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you get HTTP2 enabled it won't help much. Anybody wanting to really abuse this will probably force downgrade to HTTP1.